# React Toastify with Bootstrap 4

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, reactstrap, react-toastify

Is there any way I can use `react-toastify` with Reactstrap's `Toast` component, or the Bootstrap 4 `toast` classes? Here's my current config:

```js
import { toast } from 'react-toastify'

toast.configure({
  toastClassName: 'toast', // Bootstrap class
  bodyClassName: 'toast-body', // Another Bootstrap class
});
```

To be clear, I am using the following libraries:

- React Toastify: https://github.com/fkhadra/react-toastify
- Reactstrap: https://reactstrap.github.io

I would really like to be able to use this component as the Toast:

- https://reactstrap.github.io/components/toasts

Answer (score 0):

You can build your react component as normal and insert it instead of a plain message. The docs for react-toastify show how to do just that.

- Build your react toast component using bootstrap 4 classes/react
  bootstrap
- Place a `<ToastContainer />` in your App
- Use `toast(*)`, where * is the component you built and imported into
  App

More info on this here: https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/render-what-you-want